# Почему мы говорим "вернуть", если на самом деле мы "выводим на экран"?

Tags: javascript, терминология

"вернуть", "возвращает" в JavaScript, если по сути это "вывести на экран", "output"? При чем здесь "вернуть"?

Comment: не одним выводом на экран едины.

Comment: Kromster, вот зачем было менять, если и так все понятно? А теперь вы запутаннее сделали...

Comment: @Since Суть вопроса не понятна.

Comment: Вопрос для МЕТЫ или русского stackexchange))

Comment: Конечно не понята, прочтите мой вопрос до изменения.

Comment: Есть операции вывода на экран и есть операция возвращения значения, это два разных действия. Очевидно, без примера ваш вопрос не имеет смысла т.к. мы никогда не используем эти слова как синомимы. Ваше утверждение не является правдой, поэтому ответить "почему мы так делаем" просто невозможно.

Comment: Функция **возвращает** результат своей работы тому, кто вызвал эту функцию. Это как если бы вы послали другана за пивасиком в ближайший магазин, а он вам потом **возвращает** результат своей работы — бутылочку светлого. Результат можно выпить, а можно убрать в холодильник. Так и с результатом вызова функции: возвращённое значение можно вывести на экран, а можно ничего с ним не делать. Вывод на экран и возврат — это два совершенно различных и не связанных друг с другом действия

Answer (score 3):

В программировании эти операции являются раздельными и не являются синонимами, очевидно произошло какое-то недопонимание при их использовании. Могу предположить, что вы встретили эти операции, когда они идут одна за другой и автор статьи/книги/мануала опустил подробности.

Для короткого примера можно так сказать, операция сложения вернет сумму:

```
console.log(5 + 7)
```

Но правильная фраза будет звучать как "мы выводим на экран то, что нам вернула операция сложения чисел". То есть две операции идут друг за другом, но я опускаю часть фразы, поскольку моя цель рассказать про сложение.

По факту же происходят раздельные операции и вернувшийся результат может не выводиться на экран.

```
//возвращаем результат операции суммирования 
a = 5 + 7 

//выводим на экран совершенно другую фразу
console.log("у меня есть результат, но я вам его не покажу") 

//выводим значение переменной a на экран (никакого возврата тут нет)
console.log(a)
```

Обычно "вернула" говорят, когда происходят какие-то операции и мы получили результат. Это могут быть выражения и функции как правило. Надеюсь так понятнее будет.

Answer (score 1):

> "вернуть", "возвращает" в JavaScript, если по сути это "вывести на
>   экран", "output"? При чем здесь "вернуть"?

При том, что говорится именно про функцию, функция возвращает значение после того, как отработала. Что делать с этим значением дальше решает программист, и это не обязательно вывод на экран

```
function summ(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
const result = summ(5, 10); // функция возвращает значение, но ничего не выводит на экран
// потом мы вообще можем это на бэкенд отправить
```

Answer (score 1):

Это совершенно разные операции. Например, `console.log()` выводит текст на экран, но ничего не возвращает:

```js
x = console.log("Hello world!"); // выводит текст на экран и возвращает результат работы в переменную х
console.log(x); // х - undefined, т.е. console.log() ничего не возвращает
```

А, например, `Math.sin(x)` возвращает синус от х, но на экран ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что мы ***выводим на экран*** то, что ***вернула*** нам какая-то функция. *(или не выводим, а используем как-то иначе)*